# Change text column to integer array in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a column with comma separated integers (e.g. "25,93,1,3"). I want to change the column type to an integer array.

I have tried this, but it corrupts all the data:

```
alter table commission_data
   alter activities drop default
,  alter activities type _int4 using string_to_array(activities, ',')::_int4
,  alter activities set default '{}';
```

with the following error, staring with '=DBCException: Array type text doesn't have a component type'

How should I do this?

Comment: Your code works just fine: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c978c520ce862b68b5cf3f0c5a2b4e1b

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for testing that. I wonder if it's my database tool (dBeaver) that's causing the causing the corruption then. It does has it's fair share of bugs

Comment: Yes, do not trust `dBeaver` always verify by using another tool say `psql`. Or better yet just ditch it and move on.

Comment: Might need to look elsewhere. It worked just fine in dBeaver for me.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem - it's a dBeaver bug. Originally, I ran the script via dBeaver, then on selecting rows from that table, dBeaver showed those exception messages in the columns.

I've since checked directly via the terminal, and the data had actually been migrated correctly - no data corruption. After restarting dBeaver, it all worked correctly. Presumably dBeaver is caching the column types, and then throws an error when it gets back a different data type than it was expecting.